# Adding declarations and definitions in the IDE for runtime components

Tags: delphi, ide, runtime, declaration

I'm dealing with creating a number of components at runtime and setting their methods.  Is there a way to add the declartion and definition stubs for a component without adding it to the form and clicking the corresponding event on the events tab?

I know I can add a component temporarily to create the stub, or sometimes the help files list the declaration.  But there are a lot of features in the IDE that I have not found or used.

*Replying to comments:*

What I do currently is workable I just wondered if there was a shortcut I was missing.  To reiterate as some did not understand;  I am using component AwesomeComponent in my application.  I only need to create instances of AwesomeComponent at runtime, so it is not on my form (or perhaps is non-visual).  AmesomeComponent has an event DoSomething.  That event has a number of parameters.  In order to assign AmesomeComponent.OnDoSOmething at runtime, I need to code the event, but I don't have direct access to the procedure stub, I have to find it somewhere in documentation or create it on a dummy form to cut and paste it.  I didn't know if there was an IDE feature that was smart enough to say "Ok, I recognize this name (AwesomeComponent.OnDoSOmething) as an event and create a stub for it.  It must do essentially the same thing when double-clicking on the Events tab in the IDE.

Comment: What you mean? Say you create a `TButton` at runtime and you want to set and `EventHandler` to that button at design time? BTW _without adding it to the form and..._ you mean a `Unit` there instead of `Form`?

Comment: When you create a _component_ at runtime, you need to assign his _event handlers_ by coding it eg: `Button.OnClick := ButtonOnClick;`

Comment: What is wrong with creating the stub in the way you describe? You can always remove the link to your component later (and even remove the component) while keeping the code. It is as convenient as any alternative.

Comment: If you mean: can I do **in code** what I normally do **in the form designer**? Yes, you can. You will have to add a runtime component to the form as parent and owner too, but not to the fields of the form class.

Comment: One approach is to put the components on a form you remove from the auto-create list. This lets you design them using the visual tools as much as you want and then instance them at runtime. Only need to add the form to the uses clause to get access to them.

Comment: No, there's no magic way that the IDE can read your mind and know that when you type `procedure TForm1.TAwesomeComponentDoSomething` that you are writing the code for a `TAwesomeComponent.OnDoSomething` event handler. The easiest way to do this is just to drop the component on your form, use the Object Inspector's Events tab, choose the event you want to implement, and double-click it to generate the declaration and stub. If you're going to assign it to multiple instances you create at runtime, change it from `AwesomeCompoent1OnDoSomething` to a more suitable name.

Comment: (continued) Put some code (anything, including a comment) into the procedure stub that is generated, and then you can delete the component from the form.

Comment: @KenWhite No need for magic. The knowledge the IDE has (with background compilers, refactoring and whatnot) should suffice for the following: You type `Button.OnClick` and then press some shortcut to generate and assign a matching method `ButtonClick`.

Comment: Thank you Uli for understanding.  Thank you Ken and Brian, I will continue working this way.